# Browserstack not serving index.html by default

Tags: browser-sync

**bs-config.json**

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "./dist",
    "serveStaticOptions": {
      "extensions": [
        "html",
        "js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "startPath": "/my-app"
}
```

When I load **localhost:8000/my-app** it says `Cannot GET /my-app`, yet loading **localhost:8000/my-app/index.html** works.

It also isn't picking up  **localhost:8000/my-app/index** or Javascript files that **index.html** tries to load, unless I explicitly put the `.js` extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [options guide](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-server), maybe you can try this config:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "./dist/my-app",
    "index": "index.html",
    "serveStaticOptions": {
      "extensions": [
        "html",
        "js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```